# How to statically build ffmpeg with librtmp without root on centos 7?

Tags: gcc, compilation, ffmpeg, rtmp, static-linking

i forked STVS's batch build script [here](https://github.com/oglops/ffmpeg-static/blob/master/build.sh). only added lines for rtmp ? but why it's not working , the error i got is

```
*** Building FFmpeg ***
ERROR: librtmp not found
```

if i check the config.log file

```
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -I/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/include -I/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/include -static --static -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -pthread -I/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/include/opus -I/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/include -Wl,-z,relro -L/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/lib -c -o /var/tmp/ffconf.CIIzEs8o.o /var/tmp/ffconf.bBYD2amo.c
gcc -L/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/lib -lm -L/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/lib -lm -static -Wl,--as-needed -I/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/include -Wl,-z,relro -L/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/lib -o /var/tmp/ffconf.goVEXKQq /var/tmp/ffconf.CIIzEs8o.o -lrtmp -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz -L/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/lib -lopus -lmp3lame -lfaac -lm -pthread -lbz2 -lz -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: librtmp not found
```

i then checked my openssl install, it's installed and

```
> which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl


> ldd /usr/bin/openssl
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd19ff000)
libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x0000003358000000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x0000003357c00000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000003356c00000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000003355800000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000003357400000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x0000003355c00000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000334e800000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x000000334f000000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000334e000000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x0000003356800000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x0000003357000000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x000000334fc00000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000334ec00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000334dc00000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000003350000000)
```

which means i have libssl.so already. i tried adding -L/usr/lib64 to the configure script, but still it's not working.

previously in the build script

```
CFLAGS="-I$TARGET_DIR/include" LDFLAGS="-L$TARGET_DIR/lib -lm" ./configure --prefix=${OUTPUT_DIR:-$TARGET_DIR} --extra-cflags="-I$TARGET_DIR/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$TARGET_DIR/lib -lm" --extra-version=static --disable-debug --disable-shared --enable-static --extra-cflags=--static --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-gray --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx --disable-devices --enable-librtmp
```

i tried

```
CFLAGS="-I$TARGET_DIR/include" LDFLAGS="-L$TARGET_DIR/lib -L/usr/lib64 -lm" ./configure --prefix=${OUTPUT_DIR:-$TARGET_DIR} --extra-cflags="-I$TARGET_DIR/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$TARGET_DIR/lib -L/usr/lib64 -lm" --extra-version=static --disable-debug --disable-shared --enable-static --extra-cflags=--static --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-gray --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx --disable-devices --enable-librtmp
```

same error, what am i missing ?

edit: i'm trying this on centos 7, still same error.
i tried adding

```
--extra-libs="-lrtmp"
```

and commenting out this line in configure script

```
enabled librtmp           && require_pkg_config librtmp librtmp/rtmp.h RTMP_Socket
```

the error i got is

```
rtmp.c:(.text+0x34b): undefined reference to `BN_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `BN_set_word'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to `BN_cmp'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x382): undefined reference to `BN_copy'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x38f): undefined reference to `BN_sub_word'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x39a): undefined reference to `BN_cmp'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3a8): undefined reference to `BN_CTX_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3bf): undefined reference to `BN_mod_exp'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3c7): undefined reference to `BN_CTX_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3cc): undefined reference to `BN_value_one'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3d7): undefined reference to `BN_cmp'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3fb): undefined reference to `BN_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `DHGenerateKey':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4bd): undefined reference to `DH_generate_key'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4d0): undefined reference to `BN_hex2bn'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4f4): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x50d): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x516): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x530): undefined reference to `BN_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `InitRC4Encryption':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x5c3): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x5c8): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x5de): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x5f3): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x601): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x609): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x63e): undefined reference to `RC4_set_key'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x646): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x64b): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x661): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x673): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x681): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x689): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x6bf): undefined reference to `RC4_set_key'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `HMACsha256':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xaf9): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xafe): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xb12): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xb20): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xb30): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xb38): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `b64enc.isra.13':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc54): undefined reference to `BIO_f_base64'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc5c): undefined reference to `BIO_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc64): undefined reference to `BIO_s_mem'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc6c): undefined reference to `BIO_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc77): undefined reference to `BIO_push'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc88): undefined reference to `BIO_write'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc99): undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xce2): undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xd0e): undefined reference to `BIO_free_all'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `DHInit.constprop.21':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xd82): undefined reference to `DH_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xd91): undefined reference to `BN_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xdaa): undefined reference to `BN_hex2bn'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xdb6): undefined reference to `DH_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xdca): undefined reference to `BN_set_word'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `DHGetPublicKey.constprop.22':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xe03): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xe6e): undefined reference to `BN_bn2bin'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `DHComputeSharedSecretKey.constprop.23':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xf46): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xf5f): undefined reference to `BN_hex2bn'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xf88): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xf90): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xfb2): undefined reference to `DH_compute_key'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_Init':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1382): undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1387): undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x138c): undefined reference to `OpenSSL_add_all_digests'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1391): undefined reference to `SSLv23_method'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1399): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13b7): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_AllocServerContext':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13e8): undefined reference to `SSLv23_server_method'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13f0): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13fe): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1412): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x142c): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1451): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_Accept':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2388): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x239d): undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x23a9): undefined reference to `SSL_accept'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMPSockBuf_Fill':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2737): undefined reference to `SSL_read'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMPSockBuf_Close':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2b41): undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2b4d): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `CloseInternal':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2df4): undefined reference to `DH_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `WriteN':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2f5a): undefined reference to `RC4'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `ReadN':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4677): undefined reference to `RC4'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `HandShake.isra.18':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4ea8): undefined reference to `RC4'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4ecc): undefined reference to `RC4'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `SHandShake':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x62fc): undefined reference to `RC4'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x6321): more undefined references to `RC4' follow
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_Connect1':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x67db): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x67f0): undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x67fc): undefined reference to `SSL_connect'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `HandleInvoke.part.19':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x83d3): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x83ee): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x840e): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8424): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x842f): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8503): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8513): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8548): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8553): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8775): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8798): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x87aa): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x87b5): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a00): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a23): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a37): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a51): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a65): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a7b): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a86): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8bdd): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8bfa): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8c0e): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8c1e): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8c48): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8c53): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8ca7): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8cb9): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8ccd): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8cf5): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8d09): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8d1b): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x8d2f): more undefined references to `MD5_Update' follow
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `HandleInvoke.part.19':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8d9e): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_Init':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13c0): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_FreeServerContext':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1461): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMPSockBuf_Send':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2a50): undefined reference to `SSL_write'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(hashswf.o): In function `swfcrunch':
hashswf.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
hashswf.c:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(hashswf.o): In function `HTTP_get':
hashswf.c:(.text+0x358): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
hashswf.c:(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd'
hashswf.c:(.text+0x37c): undefined reference to `SSL_connect'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(hashswf.o): In function `RTMP_HashSWF':
hashswf.c:(.text+0xa93): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_init'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xa98): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xaba): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xb68): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xfa3): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
libavformat/libavformat.a(rtpproto.o): In function `rtp_parse_addr_list':
rtpproto.c:(.text+0x456): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/libpthread.a(libpthread.o): In function `sem_open':
(.text+0x685b): warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `add_addr_info':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2a4): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `isValidPublicKey':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x34b): undefined reference to `BN_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `BN_set_word'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to `BN_cmp'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x382): undefined reference to `BN_copy'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x38f): undefined reference to `BN_sub_word'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x39a): undefined reference to `BN_cmp'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3a8): undefined reference to `BN_CTX_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3bf): undefined reference to `BN_mod_exp'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3c7): undefined reference to `BN_CTX_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3cc): undefined reference to `BN_value_one'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3d7): undefined reference to `BN_cmp'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x3fb): undefined reference to `BN_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `DHGenerateKey':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4bd): undefined reference to `DH_generate_key'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4d0): undefined reference to `BN_hex2bn'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4f4): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x50d): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x516): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x530): undefined reference to `BN_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `InitRC4Encryption':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x5c3): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x5c8): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x5de): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x5f3): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x601): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x609): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x63e): undefined reference to `RC4_set_key'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x646): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x64b): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x661): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x673): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x681): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x689): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x6bf): undefined reference to `RC4_set_key'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `HMACsha256':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xaf9): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xafe): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xb12): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xb20): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xb30): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xb38): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `b64enc.isra.13':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc54): undefined reference to `BIO_f_base64'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc5c): undefined reference to `BIO_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc64): undefined reference to `BIO_s_mem'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc6c): undefined reference to `BIO_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc77): undefined reference to `BIO_push'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc88): undefined reference to `BIO_write'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xc99): undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xce2): undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xd0e): undefined reference to `BIO_free_all'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `DHInit.constprop.21':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xd82): undefined reference to `DH_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xd91): undefined reference to `BN_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xdaa): undefined reference to `BN_hex2bn'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xdb6): undefined reference to `DH_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xdca): undefined reference to `BN_set_word'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `DHGetPublicKey.constprop.22':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xe03): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xe6e): undefined reference to `BN_bn2bin'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `DHComputeSharedSecretKey.constprop.23':
rtmp.c:(.text+0xf46): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xf5f): undefined reference to `BN_hex2bn'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xf88): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xf90): undefined reference to `BN_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0xfb2): undefined reference to `DH_compute_key'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_Init':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1382): undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1387): undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x138c): undefined reference to `OpenSSL_add_all_digests'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1391): undefined reference to `SSLv23_method'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1399): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13b7): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_AllocServerContext':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13e8): undefined reference to `SSLv23_server_method'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13f0): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13fe): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1412): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x142c): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1451): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_Accept':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2388): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x239d): undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x23a9): undefined reference to `SSL_accept'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMPSockBuf_Fill':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2737): undefined reference to `SSL_read'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMPSockBuf_Close':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2b41): undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2b4d): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `CloseInternal':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2df4): undefined reference to `DH_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `WriteN':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2f5a): undefined reference to `RC4'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `ReadN':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4677): undefined reference to `RC4'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `HandShake.isra.18':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4ea8): undefined reference to `RC4'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x4ecc): undefined reference to `RC4'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `SHandShake':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x62fc): undefined reference to `RC4'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x6321): more undefined references to `RC4' follow
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_Connect1':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x67db): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x67f0): undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x67fc): undefined reference to `SSL_connect'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `HandleInvoke.part.19':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x83d3): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x83ee): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x840e): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8424): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x842f): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8503): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8513): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8548): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8553): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8775): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8798): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x87aa): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x87b5): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a00): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a23): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a37): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a51): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a65): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a7b): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8a86): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8bdd): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8bfa): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8c0e): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8c1e): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8c48): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8c53): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8ca7): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8cb9): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8ccd): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8cf5): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8d09): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8d1b): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x8d2f): more undefined references to `MD5_Update' follow
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `HandleInvoke.part.19':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x8d9e): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_Init':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x13c0): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMP_TLS_FreeServerContext':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x1461): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o): In function `RTMPSockBuf_Send':
rtmp.c:(.text+0x2a50): undefined reference to `SSL_write'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(hashswf.o): In function `swfcrunch':
hashswf.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
hashswf.c:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(hashswf.o): In function `HTTP_get':
hashswf.c:(.text+0x358): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
hashswf.c:(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd'
hashswf.c:(.text+0x37c): undefined reference to `SSL_connect'
/home/oglop/Downloads/ffmpeg-static-git2/target/lib/librtmp.a(hashswf.o): In function `RTMP_HashSWF':
hashswf.c:(.text+0xa93): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_init'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xa98): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xaba): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xb68): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
hashswf.c:(.text+0xfa3): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffprobe_g] Error 1
```

Comment: You need to have librtmp.a on your machine. Do you have it? Where is it located?

Comment: yes i have it, it was built by the build script as seen in my forked version. it's in `$TARGET_DIR/lib` folder, in my case it's at `/usr/tmp/tmp/ffmpeg-static-test/target/lib` the build script created this folder `target` and put all the compiled dependencies inside it ( because we used `--prefix` in the `./configure` call )

Comment: Double check you have the filename you think you have at the place you think you have it. The makefile says `LIBRTMP=librtmp/librtmp.a` which means you are probably off by one level of directories.

Comment: Do you even need librtmp? FFmpeg contains native support for RTMP.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard yes it should support rtmp but last time I tried it, it didn't download the rpmpte link I gave to it.  That's why I wanted to try librtmp

Comment: sorry i was wrong, just tried again, yes ffmpeg can download the rtmpte link already, because the builtin support for rtmp is working this time. but out of curiosity, how to make it compile whith external librtmp like in this case, if i did want external librtmp and used --enable-librtmp ?